# Auto Version Numbering

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I'm looking for a steer in terms of version numbering. I'd like to auto numbering for each change/release.

We are using BitBucket for our code storage, using Visual Code for an Editor and have multiple branches, dev, staging and live. We also have multiple devs, working on different things at once. All devs are working on OSX

Any help, would be most appreciated.

Comment: something like `npm version` ?

Comment: What does this do? :)

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be on the right track but how do I know the version number?

Comment: You can also bump the current version.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response.

Comment: npm version can also increment a version number without you knowing what the number is. it's all explained in the docs.